# How to determine an Android View's size in pixels?

Tags: android

Is there a direct programmatic way to get a fill_parent View's pixel height and width? For instance a view in a grid layout in a tab. Or do I have to get the window size and subtract the static sizes of the views around it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the views parent by calling `myView.getParent()` and with `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` you get the pixel you need.
the documentation is providing more information to this topic
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: what if the height returned is zero?

Answer (score 0):

There's the `onMeasure()` method, not sure if that will do what you need. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html