# Viewpager with large bitmaps

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

Hi I'm trying to build something like an horizontal gallery where I can add or remove pages using images from my gallery/camera.

I'm trying to make it work with large bitmaps so I'm using an algorithm to scale the bitmap and set it to the imageview of each page.
The algorithm requires the width/height of the ImageView (to scale down).

The problem I have is that when my custom PagerAdapter method is executed, the width/height of the ImageView is not yet known (getWidth/getHeight return 0), so it does not work:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.document_page, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // Obtain the image file URI
        // Call algorithm to get scaled bitmap using ImageView width and height --> PROBLEM: imageView.getWidth()/Height() return 0!!
        // Set ImageView with scaled bitmap to avoid OutOfMemory Exception

        return view;
}
```

What do you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: This question just came to my mind again when watching two little tutorials by Chet Haase. They've just been uploaded and cover `inSampleSize` (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12cB7gnL6po) and Bitmap loading performance in general (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8). Make sure to check if you can use some of the knowledge to optimize your code and to avoid the Exception.

Comment: Finally, you solve it? I've the same problem

Answer (score 3):

### Scaling the image client-side:

You don't need your own algorithm to scale an image if it's already on your device. An `ImageView` has a [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) that you can set like this:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
```

(or in XML with the `android:scaleType` attribute).

The remaining question is how to get the image from your URL to display in the `ImageView`. Use libraries such as [SmartImageView](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/) or [Android-Query](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading) (more powerful) to achieve that in an asynchronous manner (i.e. without blocking your UI thread).

With SmartImageView, for example, you are able to use something like this:

```
myImageView.setImageUrl("http://www.awesomeimages.com/myawesomeimage.jpg");
```

Just read the examples on that page, there are far more options.

### Scaling server-side

If you have some kind of resize algorithm that is triggered e.g. by certain URL parameters, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935072/1140682) and pass the width and height as you desire (maybe with one of the above-mentioned libraries).

As you said that `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return `0`, please look at the `layout_width` and `layout_height` that you have set for your `ImageView`. If it's `fill_parent`, there should be no problem, but if it *has* to be `wrap_content`, consider using a local, transparent dummy image with same aspect ratio as your final image (until the "real image" has been set).

Comment: Thanks but I'm using images from SDCard, so the files have to be decoded using BitmapFactory.decodeFile. decodeFile receives a parameter to indicate some options, one of them is inSampleSize which is used to scale down. If I don't use this, I could get OutOfMemoryException. The algorithm that I'm using is explained here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: okay, so did you try my second solution then? An imageView that has its width or height set to `fill_parent` usually returns the correct pixel size on `getWidth()` or `getHeight()`. Otherwise, that dummy image approach could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Use bitmap factory with justInbounds option. So it will just return the dimension of bitmap without loading bitmap to the ram.

```
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with my problem. I need to know the width and height of my imageview, not the bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood.you may try getMeasuredHeight() or you may get this values by overriding onLayout() method of the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

try to sample the bitmap to the size of the screen (use [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) in order to get the resolution of the bitmap , and [displayMatrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) in order to get the resolution of the screen ) .

if there is no transparency , you might also wish to use the [RGB 565 format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) of bitmap decoding instead of 8888 . this will save about 1/4 of the memory being used .

in any case , i suggest [reading this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) of handling bitmaps .

Comment: I read that tutorial, the algorithm I mention is that one. As you can see the method explained there "calculateInSampleSize" has reqWidth and reqHeight parameters. Those must be the width and height of the imageview, this is the problem. My imageview does not have a fixed width/height, it uses fill_parent. And getWidth/getHeight of the imageview is returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but I came up with a solution: create a function and call it from "public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position)".

The trick is: the created function will be set to post execute after some miliseconds (to do that you will use the Handler object)

Doing that way the "instantiateItem" will be already done, and view elements will have widths and heights values set.

Bellow is some sample code on how to proceed:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
{
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_list_item,container,false);

    TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pagerTextView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.pagerImageView);

    ... //stuff that don't need the width and height

    Handler handle = new Handler();
    handle.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        //here the widths and heights values should be already set
       //now you can test the view.getWidth() and view.getHeight()

       if(view.getWidth()!=0 && view.getHeight()!=0)
       {
          //now you sare safe to call the android algorithm for scaling large bitmaps
       }

    }, 100); //it will wait 100 miliseconds to execute

  return view;
}
```

100 miliseconds is an arbitrary number, maybe too much!!

I recommend you to use a loop or recursive function to guarantee that the block inside the "if" statement will be executed, that way you can use even smaller miliseconds.

In my project I used a recursive function that called itself until the "if" block is executed, and I set to 5 miliseconds.

It should work without a loop or recursive methods, just by setting an arbitrary number like 100 and testing later, but you can't assure that the app will behave the same for all devices, for one can be fast and for other may take a little longer for view to be ready, you never know.